# How to copy files from remote PC-A-B to local drive?

Tags: ssh, scp

**Introduction**. My work computer (`PC-B`) is accessible only from inside the network (`PC-A`) and I can connect to PC-B via SSH in one command: `ssh -J user@PC-A user@PC-B`.

**Problem**. I need to copy folders from remote PC-B to my local drive.

I tried:

**(a)** from my local PC: `scp -r user@PC-A user@PC-B:/path/to/folder /home/` but it does not work.

**(b)** while remotely connected to PC-B: `scp path/to/folder userHome@PC-HOME` - connection timed out.

Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ProxyJump` directly in the scp command:

```
scp -r -o 'ProxyJump user@PC-A' user@PC-B:/path/to/folder /home/
```

You can also create an alias in ~/.ssh/config and do not type address
of the proxy server each time:

```
Host PC-A-alias
User user
Hostname PC-A

Host PC-B-alias
User user
Hostname PC-B
ProxyJump  PC-A-alias
```

Now you can just use PC-B-alias with ssh, scp and other commands that use SSH such as rsync.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using the first approach I was able to download all the data. Thanks!